# How can I concat two objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My script JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
    var customer = {"name":"John", "address":'London'};
    var products = [
        {"product_name":"clothes", "quantity":1, "price":1000},
        {"product_name":"trousers", "quantity":1, "price":500},
        {"product_name":"shoes", "quantity":1, "price":2000}
    ];
</script>
```

I want to concat the objects. So I want the result like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: `const result = { ...customer, products }`

Comment: customer.products = products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dot-syntax and the `=` operator to set a property of the `customer` object:

```js
var customer = {"name":"John", "address":'London'};
var products = [
  {"product_name":"clothes", "quantity":1, "price":1000},
  {"product_name":"trousers", "quantity":1, "price":500},
  {"product_name":"shoes", "quantity":1, "price":2000}
];

customer.products = products;

console.log(customer)
```

If you don't want `customer` to be changed, you can use the spread syntax instead:

```js
var customer = {"name":"John", "address":'London'};
var products = [
  {"product_name":"clothes", "quantity":1, "price":1000},
  {"product_name":"trousers", "quantity":1, "price":500},
  {"product_name":"shoes", "quantity":1, "price":2000}
];

const customerAndProducts = { ...customer, products : products }

console.log(customer)
console.log(customerAndProducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property directly in customers:

```
var customer = {"name":"John", "address":'London'};
customer.products =  [
    {"product_name":"clothes", "quantity":1, "price":1000},
    {"product_name":"trousers", "quantity":1, "price":500},
    {"product_name":"shoes", "quantity":1, "price":2000}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign would do the trick: `customer = Object.assign(customer, { products: products })`